# CSS3 transition how to, for radio choice buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a radio choice button that I wish to transition with a slide effect with CSS3 instead of just a fade in/out effect that I have currently with CSS3.

Can it be done with purely CSS3? I don't want to use any jquery, as I would like it stay simple and clean as possible.

Thank you.

```css
body {
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
/* Hiding Radio */

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
/* switch-bar */

.switch-canvas {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-canvas">
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" checked="" />
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" />
  <label for="male">Male</label>
</div>
```

Comment: For the next time, please google before.. http://cssdeck.com/labs/better-css-toggle-switches.

Comment: @Mosh Feu I dont want checkboxes Mosh, I want radio buttons, its more logical, you either pick male or female. I have seen that page before

Comment: In this demo you have radio buttons too.. pay attention..

Comment: @Mosh I was paying attention I see, but the radio buttons are seperate radio buttons, my styling is way different man, can you see?

Comment: OK. Why can't you use just one radio button. If it's checked is woman and if not it's man or something..

Comment: @Mosh radio buttons are either one or the other, checkbox is on or off. radio buttons are the logical choice, and the radio buttons in the url you suggested dont work individually. I dont want checkboxes. Can I transition this with the slide effect somehow in CSS3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112295/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-krystyna).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was added span after the radio buttons so he will be the white rounded square who mark the option that selected.

```css
body {
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
/* Hiding Radio */

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
/* switch-bar */

.switch-canvas {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  /*font-size: 0;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position:relative;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  float:left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*label {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
width: 50%;
height: 40px;
color: #222;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}*/
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  /*background-color: #fff;*/
  color: green;
  /*border-radius: 2px;*/
}

span {
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform:translate(0);
}

#male:checked ~ span {
  transform:translateX(100%);
  left:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-canvas">
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" checked="" />
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" />
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/tazahek/edit?html,css

**It's not working on IE8 and older (obviously)**